# ASPX file output differs from SQL stored proc

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am developing an ASPX file that returns results from a SQL stored proc into a data adapter, which is then displayed in a GridView.  But the problem is that the numbers do not match between the SQL stored proc and Gridview.  They are close, but are off just slightly: 3 thousandths.  So the SQL Stored proc gives me 0.199, but in Gridview this same value = .203.  And it doesn't appear to be a rounding issue either.  Also, I looked at the Gridview properties, but I didn't see anything that would be causing this.  All of the values for this one column are off by the same margin.

What troubleshooting steps can u recommend?  I am using VB in a VS 2008 Shell for SSRS, SSIS.  Here is my code from the main ASPX file:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" Src="../Global.vb"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="ChartDirector" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OleDB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Math" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="chart" Namespace="ChartDirector" Assembly="netchartdir" %>

<HTML>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VB" RUNAT="Server">
        Sub Page_Load(Sender as Object, E as EventArgs)
            If Not IsPostback Then 
                Dim YearDate as date = "1/  1/05"               
                Dim arrYear as New ArrayList()

                While YearDate <= Today
                    arrYear.Add(YearDate.ToString("yyyy"))
                    YearDate = YearDate.AddYears(1) 
                End While

                dYear.DataSource = arrYear
                dYear.DataBind()
                dYear.SelectedValue = Today.AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyy")

                Dim arrLevel as New ArrayList()

                arrLevel.Add("All")
                arrLevel.Add("Inquiries")
                arrLevel.Add("All Complaints")
                arrLevel.Add("Elevated Complaints")
                arrLevel.Add("Non-Elevated Complaints")

                dLevel.DataSource = arrLevel
                dLevel.DataBind()
                dLevel.SelectedValue = "All Complaints"

                '********* Set Month dropdown ************
                Dim EndMonth as Date
                dim StartMonth as Date = "1/1/" & dYear.SelectedValue
                Dim arrMonth as New ArrayList()

                EndMonth  = "12/1/" & dYear.SelectedValue

                While StartMonth <= EndMonth
                    arrMonth.Add(MonthName(month(StartMonth)))
                    StartMonth = StartMonth.AddMonths(1)
                End While

                dMonth.DataSource = arrMonth
                dMonth.DataBind()

                If dYear.SelectedValue = Today.ToString("yyyy") then
                    dMonth.SelectedValue = MonthName(month(Today.AddMonths(-1))) 
                End If

                Label1.Text = "Complaint Trending List"
                btnExport.Visible = "false"

            Else
                Main()
                btnExport.Visible = "true"
            End If          
        End Sub

        Sub Main()          
            Dim TheLevel As Integer
            Dim TitleLevel As String
            Dim FirstMonthDate As Date = dMonth.SelectedValue & "/1/" & dYear.SelectedValue
            Dim LastMonthDate as date = GlobalFunctions.GlobalF.MonthLastDate(FirstMonthDate)
            Dim arrMonthYear As New ArrayList()

            Select Case dLevel.SelectedValue
                Case "All"
                    TheLevel = 5
                    TitleLevel = "Inquiries and Complaints"
                Case "Inquiries"
                    TheLevel = 0
                    TitleLevel = "Inquiries"
                Case "All Complaints"
                    TheLevel = 3
                    TitleLevel = "All Complaints"
                Case "Elevated Complaints"
                    TheLevel = 2
                    TitleLevel = "Elevated Complaints"
                Case "Non-Elevated Complaints"
                    TheLevel = 1
                    TitleLevel = "Non-Elevated Complaints"
            End Select

            Dim dataPG As New System.Data.DataSet
            Dim dataSD As New System.Data.DataSet
            Dim dataPCHART As New System.Data.DataSet

            PrintMessageGrid.DataSource = GlobalFunctions.GlobalF.GetComplaintTrendingList6(FirstMonthDate, LastMonthDate, TheLevel)
            PrintMessageGrid.DataBind()

            Dim ListDataTable As DataTable
            Dim ListDataRow As DataRow
            ListDataTable = New DataTable

            ListDataTable.Columns.Add("Product Group")
            ListDataTable.Columns.Add("Short Description")
            ListDataTable.Columns.Add("p-value")
            ListDataTable.Columns.Add("LCL")
            ListDataTable.Columns.Add("UCL")
            ListDataTable.Columns.Add("Six In A Row")
            ListDataTable.Columns.Add("Exceeds Limits")
            'ListDataTable.Columns.Add("Selected")
            'ListDataTable.Columns.Add("Total")

            Label1.Text = dMonth.SelectedValue & " " & dYear.SelectedValue & " Complaint Trending List"
        End Sub

        Sub PrintMessageGrid_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, _
       ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)
            If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                Dim exceeds_limits As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Exceeds_Limit"))
                Dim six_in_a_row As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Six_In_A_Row"))
                If exceeds_limits = 1 Or six_in_a_row = 1 Then
                    e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
                End If
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub btnExport_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
            GlobalFunctions.GlobalF.GridViewToExcel(PrintMessageGrid, Response)
        End Sub


    </SCRIPT>
    <head> 
        <title>AMD QA Metrics</title>
    </head>
    <body onbeforeunload="LoadBusy();"> 
        <script language="javascript" src="../includes/CastleBusyBox.js"></script>
        <div style="font-size:18pt; font-family:verdana; font-weight:bold">
           <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <hr style="color:#000080"/>
        <form runat="Server" method="post" id="Form1">
            <table>
                <tr><th>Month</th><th>Year</th><th>Level</th></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><ASP:DROPDOWNLIST id="dMonth" runat="Server" autopostback="false" /></td>
                    <td><ASP:DROPDOWNLIST id="dYear" runat="Server" autopostback="false" /></td>
                    <td><ASP:DROPDOWNLIST id="dLevel" runat="Server" autopostback="false" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <asp:Button id="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="submit" />  
            <br />  
            <br />
            <span onclick="busyBox.Enabled = false;">
                <asp:Button id="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export List to Excel" onclick="btnExport_Click" autopostback="false" />
            </span>
            <ASP:GridView id="PrintMessageGrid" runat="server" AUTOGENERATECOLUMNS="true" ShowHeader="true" OnRowDataBound="PrintMessageGrid_RowDataBound">
                    <HEADERSTYLE BackColor = "#336699" ForeColor = "#ffffff" Font-Bold = "true" />
                </ASP:GridView> 
            <iframe id="BusyBoxIFrame" name="BusyBoxIFrame" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" ondrop="return false;">
            </iframe>
            <SCRIPT>
                // Instantiate our BusyBox object
                var busyBox = new BusyBox("BusyBoxIFrame", "busyBox", 4, "../Images/gears_ani_", ".gif", 125, 147, 207);
            </SCRIPT>
        </form>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

And portions of the global.vb file:

```vb
    Namespace GlobalFunctions
        Public Class GlobalF

            'Added by Ryan on 4/14/11
        Public Shared Function GetComplaintTrendingList6(ByVal FirstMonth As DateTime, ByVal LastMonth As DateTime, ByVal rowLevel As Integer) As DataSet
            Dim DSPageData As New System.Data.DataSet
            Dim param(2) As SqlClient.SqlParameter

            param(0) = New SqlParameter("@FirstMonthDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)
            param(0).Value = FirstMonth
            param(1) = New SqlParameter("@LastMonthDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)
            param(1).Value = LastMonth
            param(2) = New SqlParameter("@TheLevel", SqlDbType.Int)
            param(2).Value = rowLevel

            ''# A Using block will ensure the .Dispose() method is called for these variables, even if an exception is thrown 
            ''# This is IMPORTANT - not disposing your connections properly can result in an unrespsonsive database 
            Using conn As New SQLConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("AMDMetricsDevConnectionString")), _
           cmd As New SQLCommand("ComplaintTrendingList6", conn), _
            da As New SQLDataAdapter(cmd)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param)

                da.Fill(DSPageData)
            End Using

            Return DSPageData
        End Function
...
        Public Shared Function MonthLastDate(ByVal TheDate As Date)
            Select Case TheDate.Month
                Case 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12
                    MonthLastDate = TheDate.Year & "-" & TheDate.Month & "-31"
                Case 4, 6, 9, 11
                    MonthLastDate = TheDate.Year & "-" & TheDate.Month & "-30"
                Case 2
                    If (CInt(TheDate.Year) Mod 4) = 0 Then
                        MonthLastDate = TheDate.Year & "-" & TheDate.Month & "-29"
                    Else
                        MonthLastDate = TheDate.Year & "-" & TheDate.Month & "-28"
                    End If
            End Select
        End Function
```

Comment: Why did this post get down voted, please provide feedback when you down vote, so that the poster can improve his posts the next time, or edit them

Comment: I don't understand either why this was down-voted.  Did I do something wrong?  What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to debug into this to find what the values in question are at what steps.

If you look at the result of `GlobalFunctions.GlobalF.GetComplaintTrendingList6(FirstMonthDate, LastMonthDate, TheLevel)` directly when debugging the page, what do the numeric values in question look like?

If you step into that function and look at the contents of `DSPageData` after it's filled, what do the numeric values look like?

If you take the command from `cmd` with the given parameters and execute it directly on the database, what do the numeric values look like?

If you run a trace on the database and catch the actual execution command being sent for the stored procedure, does it match what you think it should match?  Run it manually exactly as it's being sent to the server and see what the results look like.

Comment: Thanks David.  I would like to do this and have done so using other versions of VS.  However, this is the shell and I don't seem to have the debug options.  I can set breakpoints, but all of the Debug functionality is greyed out.  This may be because I can only create SSAS/SSIS/SSRS projects.

Comment: I don't know how/if I can run a trace on the DB or any of the other things u mentioned with this limited version of VS

Comment: @salvationishere: I haven't used that version, but I would _hope_ there's some way to step into those breakpoints somehow.  If not, you may be left with some poor man's debugging by just outputting the values you need to some other source at runtime.  Basically just adding a ton of logging statements and then running the code.  For the trace, what database/version are you using?  If this is MS SQL Server then you should have installed or access to a program called SQL Server Profiler, even if it's on the server.

Comment: I can't create new traces unfortunately; after starting profiler and clicking new trace, it says I must be a member of sysadmin to do this.  This is a company laptop and I don't have privileges to do this.  Regarding poor man's debugging, which sources could I output this too?  Msgbox?  This is a table though, not a text box.

Comment: @salvationishere: For the profiler it sounds like you need a DB admin to help with that.  It's a debugging tool, you either need access to it or someone with access needs to assist you.  That's a business limitation, not a technical one :)  For the debugging output, I'd recommend logging to a file.  Log4Net is my logging system of choice, but even just manually writing to a file in the code will work.  You can also serialize objects to XML (DataSets serialize, don't they?) and output them to files.